# Multiple search queries in wp query using query string in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, search

Im trying to query my posts depending on what is in the query string in the url.

I have two query string variables. Keyword and location. I want to filter posts if just the keyword is entered, if just the location is entered or if both are entered to be more precise. I want to go off the post title. How do i structure this? Heres what i've started trying...

```
<?php
                    echo $keywords = $_GET["search_keywords"];
                    echo $location = $_GET["search_location"];


            // the query to set the posts per page to 3
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array('posts_per_page' => 8,
                'paged' => $paged ,
                'post_type' => 'job_listing',
                'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key' => '_job_title',
                        'value' => $keywords,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )

                )
            );

          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like these:

```
 if( !empty( get_query_var( 'search_keywords' ) ) ){
    $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => '_job_title', 'value' => get_query_var( 'search_keywords' ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
}

if( !empty( get_query_var( 'search_location' ) ) ){
    $meta_query[] = array( 'key' => '_job_title', 'value' => get_query_var( 'search_location' ), 'compare' => 'LIKE' );
}

if( count( $meta_query ) > 1 ){
    $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
}

if( count( $meta_query ) > 0 ){
    $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```